# Horizontally aligning textbox with label when the two are in different divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, textbox, label

I am trying to align a series of text boxes with their corresponding labels.  Since they are in two different divs, I am unable to use the inherit keyword.  I have tried using the javascript/jquery code below to align the pairs of elements, but `$(tb).css('left')` just returns `auto`.  Does anyone know how to achieve this alignment using html, css, and/or javascript/jquery and without using a table?

```
$(function() {
    $('#infoLabels label').each(function(idx,lbl) {
        var tb = $('#' + lbl.htmlFor);

        ($(tb).width() > $(this).width()) ? $(this).width($(tb).width()) : $(tb).width($(this).width());
        $(this).css('left',$(tb).css('left'));                
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apandit/k5max5fw/1/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5max5fw/4/)**

**CSS Only**

Using table-like displaying with `display : table` for the whole div container, `display : table-row` for the row and `display : table-cell` for each cells, you can avoid using `<table></table>` and concentrate in the shape of your element using CSS only.

You have a fully compatibility with all device upon IE8 and Android 4.1+ (device with version before are not supported, beware of the previous Android). [More information on caniuse.com for display table, table-row, table-cell support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using some lines of CSS.

```
.info-table{ display:table }
#infoLabels, #infoBoxes{ display:table-row }
#infoLabels > span, #infoBoxes > span{ display:table-cell; }
```

Now the div structure acts like a table.
http://jsfiddle.net/k5max5fw/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be perfectly acceptable to use a table in this case. If for whatever reason you would prefer not to, you can use a CSS solution to achieve what you need by setting the widths of the `span` elements containing the `label` and the `input` elements. Try this:

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
span:nth-child(1) {
    width: 245px;
}
span:nth-child(2),
span:nth-child(3) {
    width: 45px;
}
span input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" class="page-footer">
    <div class="info-table">
        <div id="infoLabels"> 
            <span><label for="time">Time</label></span>
            <span><label for="value">Value</label></span>
            <span><label for="flag">Flag</label></span>
        </div>
        <div id="infoBoxes"> 
            <span><input id="time" type="text" /></span>
            <span><input id="value" type="text" /></span>
            <span><input id="flag" type="text" /></span>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html code,

```
               <div id="footer" class="page-footer">
               <div class="info-table">
                   <div id="infoLabels">
                       <span><label for="time">Time</label></span></br>
                       <span><label for="value">Value</label></span></br>
                       <span><label for="flag">Flag</label></span></br>
                   </div>
                   <div id="infoBoxes">
                       <span><input id="time" type="text" size="40" /></span></br>
                       <span><input id="value" type="text" size="7" /></span></br>
                       <span><input id="flag" type="text" size="7" /></span></br>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Add  after each span tag.

css code,

```
#infoLabels
{
    float:left;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the requirements in the question.